How to embed image in email message using curl interface to SendGrid
I am trying to use the curl interface to SendGrid to send an email with an embedded image (not an attachment) and cannot work out the correct syntax.  I am also on Windows, so the issues with the json quotes and the windows command line mean I have to create a file and use the curl -d option.
Here's my curl command:
curl --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send --request POST \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer mybearertokenstring " \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d "@E:\temp\curl_RCC_20240506104528.tmp"

Here's my temp file contents:
{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "myemail@domain.com"}]}], "from": {"email": "fromemail@domain.com"}, "subject": "folio number", "content": [{"type": "text/html", "value": "<html><body>Image file = E:/images/allproplogo.jpg<br><img height="326" width="620" id="Picture 2" class="center" src="cid:image0001" /></body></html>"}] ,"files": [{"filename":"allproplogo.jpg", "type": "image/jpeg", "cid":"image0001", "content":"base64encodedimage"}]}

In response, I get this error message
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Request","field":null,"help":null}]}

I have tried various combinations of base64 encrypting the message, but I either get this message or a bad UTF8 response.

A solution to this would be to upload your image to some service, get its public URL and insert it into an .html file in the src="" of the <img /> tag.
