Pipe a file as an attachment into sendgrid's curl API
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer SG.rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr" \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "me@me.com"}]}],"from": {"email": "me@me.com"},"subject": "Sending with SendGrid is Fun","content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "and easy to do anywhere, even with cURL"}], "attachments": [{"content": "/home/file.gz", "type": "application/tar+gzip", "filename": "file.gz"}]}'

The problem is that "file.gz" just comes through with "/home/file.gz" rather than it's contents. How do I modify this command to put the files contents and essentially attach the whole file?
Tried messing around with piping things into that line but I can't figure out how to do it with a single command.

There doesn't seem to be any pipe here. This appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78438427/how-to-embed-image-in-email-message-using-curl-interface-to-sendgrid although it doesn't have any good answer.
